# Sharepoint 2010 MySite feature Stapling Error

Tags: my-site, feature-stapling

In our environment  i had created a feature stapler which will brand the personal site of users so that it will follow the same branding all over the site collection but when a user is creating a blog inside his personal site it is showing default master page .Can anyone suggest me how to make the blog also to have the same master page

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you configured your staples you might want to consider attaching it to the Blog Site template too (most likely you attached it to SPSPERS#0). You would need to target the template BLOG#0 also.

Simply add another line to your stapling feature as follows

```
<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="<GUID OF FEATURE HERE>" TemplateName="BLOG#0" />
```

Also you would probably would like to validate whether your features are compatible also.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Hi Marius .. I did the same but its not taking effect can you help me

Comment: Hi Marius when i go to the blog and go to manage site feature and enable SharePoint Server Publishing then it is getting the branding .My features are enabling the publishing at site collection level but it is not enabling the site level am i missing something??

Comment: The Publishing Infrastructure features are of 2 types, related to their scope (Site Collection or Sub-Site), which also means that you need to activate different features, as follows:
 At the site collection level F6924D36-2FA8-4f0b-B16D-06B7250180FA (e.g. when you create the My Sites for each user) - which you probably do already and the "SharePoint Server Publishing feature" with id 94C94CA6-B32F-4da9-A9E3-1F3D343D7ECB . For a sub-site to become a full-publishing site you need to have them both activated. A word of warning: BLOG site is NOT meant to be a Publishing Site

Comment: Hi marius ia m adding the features as follows  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="F6924D36-2FA8-4f0b-B16D-06B7250180FA" TemplateName="SPSPERS#0" />
  <!-- SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure - Scope: Site -->

  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="94C94CA6-B32F-4da9-A9E3-1F3D343D7ECB" TemplateName="SPSPERS#0"  />
  <!-- SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure - Scope: Site -->

  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="94C94CA6-B32F-4da9-A9E3-1F3D343D7ECB" TemplateName="BLOG#0"  />
  <!-- SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure - Scope: Site -->
  Is there any thing else i need..

Comment: I believe you need to validate the scope of your Stappler (available are FARM, WEB APPLICATION and SITE COLLECTION level), see here example doing the exact same thing http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/05/feature-stapling.html

Comment: Hi Can you see the down hyperlink i am facing the same problem as him ..Can you please help mee http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411225/sharepoint-2010-mysite-blog-branding-with-publishing-not-working

Comment: I would suggest 2 things: 1. try you stapler on a regular BLOG site because Blog sites activated in MySites have a specificity in terms of activation. 2. what you could do is use WebProvisioned event to activate the feature by code.

Comment: do you have any news on your problem, still standing?

Comment: Yes Marius i am able to apply feature stapling to the blog but when somebody clicks on the blog document library heading it is going to pages folder and showing empty.